# glCreateShader создает ноль, вместно нормального числа

Tags: java, android

Пишу для android. вот написал версию для opengles 3. проблема в том что glCreateShader создает ноль, вместо нормального числа.
вот код.

```
package com.example.test_opengl;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.*;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;

import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;


public class GL3 extends GLES30 implements GL_wrap {
    private int uniform_transform;
    private int uniform_ortho;
    private float[] ortho;
    private Activity activity;
    private int SHADERS = 1;
    private int program[];
    private final int SPRITE = 0;
    private String sprite_vertex_str =
    "#version 300 es" +
    "layout ( location = 0 ) in vec2 position;" +
    "layout ( location = 1 ) in vec2 tex_coord;" +
    "uniform mat4 transform;" +
    "uniform mat4 ortho;" +
    "out vec2 v_tex_coord;" +
    "void main ( ) {" +
    "  gl_Position = ortho * transform * vec4 ( position, 0.0, 1.0 );" +
    "  v_tex_coord = tex_coord;" +
    "}";
    private String sprite_fragment_str =
    "#version 300 es" +
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "in vec2 v_tex_coord;" +
    "layout ( location = 0 ) out vec4 out_color;" +
    "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
    "void main ( ) {" +
    "  out_color = texture ( s_texture, v_tex_coord );" +
    "}";

    @Override
    public void compile_shader() {
        program = new int[SHADERS];
        program[SPRITE] = load_program ( SPRITE );
        GLES30.glUseProgram(program[SPRITE]);
        uniform_transform = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(program[SPRITE], "transform");
        uniform_ortho = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(program[SPRITE], "ortho");
    }
    private int load_program ( final int type ) {
        switch ( type ) {
            case SPRITE:
            {
                int vertex = load_shader(GLES30.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, sprite_vertex_str);
                int fragment = load_shader(GLES30.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, sprite_fragment_str);
                int program = glCreateProgram();
                GLES30.glAttachShader(program, vertex);
                GLES30.glAttachShader(program, fragment);
                GLES30.glLinkProgram(program);
                return program;
            }

            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    private int load_shader ( int type, String shader_src ) {
        int shader = GLES30.glCreateShader(type);
        GLES30.glShaderSource(shader, shader_src);
        GLES30.glCompileShader(shader);
        return shader;

    }

    @Override
    public int get_program ( int type ) {
        return program[type];
    }

    @Override
    public void Viewport(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        GLES30.glViewport(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void ClearColor(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha) {
        GLES30.glClearColor(red, green, blue, alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void Clear(int type) {
        GLES30.glClear(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw_sprite(Sprite sprite) {
        GLES30.glUseProgram(program[SPRITE]);
        GLES30.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES30.glBindBuffer (GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, sprite.texture_id);

        GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv (uniform_transform, 1, false, FloatBuffer.wrap(sprite.pos));
        GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv (uniform_ortho, 1, false, FloatBuffer.wrap(ortho));

        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, FloatBuffer.wrap(sprite.vertex));
        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, FloatBuffer.wrap(sprite.texture));

        GLES30.glDrawArrays(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        GLES30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GLES30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        ortho = glm.ortho(0.0f, (float) width, 0.0f, (float) height, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    }

    @Override
    public void set_activity(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int create_texture_id(Sprite sprite) {
        int texture_id = 0;
        IntBuffer t = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        GLES30.glGenTextures(1, t );
        texture_id = t.get(0);
        GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

        GLES30.glTexImage2D (GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA, sprite.width, sprite.height, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ByteBuffer.wrap(sprite.data));
        GLES30.glTexParameteri ( GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES30.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES30.glTexParameteri ( GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES30.GL_NEAREST);
        return texture_id;
    }

    @Override
    public float[] set_size_vertex(float w, float h) {
        float[] vert = new float[12];
        vert[0] = 0;
        vert[1] = 0;
        vert[2] = 0;
        vert[3] = h;
        vert[4] = w;
        vert[5] = 0;
        vert[6] = w;
        vert[7] = 0;
        vert[8] = w;
        vert[9] = h;
        vert[10] = 0;
        vert[11] = h;
        return vert;
    }

    @Override
    public float[] set_size_texture(float w, float h) {
        float[] tex = new float[12];
        tex[0] = 0;
        tex[1] = 1;
        tex[2] = 0;
        tex[3] = 0;
        tex[4] = 1;
        tex[5] = 1;
        tex[6] = 1;
        tex[7] = 1;
        tex[8] = 1;
        tex[9] = 0;
        tex[10] = 0;
        tex[11] = 0;
        return tex;
    }


}
```

Comment: щас проверю, но пока гулял по улице, подумал что компиляцию шейдеров надо вставлять в контекст, когда opengl создался.

Comment: Чел, только попробуй на java написать норм игру!!! Это будет как майнкрафт, норм игра, тупая оптимизация

Comment: @Данил я подумаю.

Answer (score 0):

код написан почти правильно, надо было указать после `#version 300 es\n` символ перехода на новую строку.